# Scala to JavaScript compilation effective?

Tags: javascript, scala

I just read about the [java 2 javascript parser](http://www.j2js.com/scala-demo/index.html) and the demo with scala.

Do you have any experience with this framework?

What about performance?

Can i use existing JS code/frameworks?

I appreciate any help.

### EDIT

This is a very good scala to javascript cross compiler:
https://www.scala-js.org/

Comment: The site even *mentions* that it's a "proof of concept", so chances are that it's **not** production ready or fast.

Comment: please don't abstract javascript. it becomes a nightmare if you want to interface with existing javascript code. The only successful compiler down to js is coffeescript.

Comment: I gonna try coffescript. seems pretty

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did this more than a year ago. Performance is ok, but code size tends to be big. I would not recommend it for production, but can give away the code if usefull.
There are other efforts to run Scala on the browser. Best would be to create a JavaScript backend to an existing Scala compiler.

Here are some other projects to look after:

http://greedy.github.com/scala/

https://github.com/scalagwt

https://github.com/alvaroc1/s2js

https://github.com/kripken/emscripten

http://jscala.org/

Comment: which efforts to run scala in the browser do you know?

Comment: @axaluss: I added some links to these efforts.

Comment: @axaluss: All pretty experimental and not well documented imho.

Comment: @amadeus "can give away the code if usefull" - Yes, any code or pointers on getting started would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Yang There is an update on http://github.com/decatur/j2js-compiler explaining why Scala is not supported

Answer (score 2):

I've never found these "language X to JavaScript" tools to be worth using. Debugging, quality of code generation, interfacing and using native JS libraries, etc., etc. mostly get compromised. CoffeeScript is an exception, because it is a new syntax for JavaScript, not an entirely separate and unrelated language.

If you need to use JS (or another language for that matter), embrace it and learn it.

Comment: Do you stand by your comment also for GWT?

Comment: If you do not code plain JavaScript for the browser, be it a different language or a JS extension/framework, please do it for this reason: **Tool support**, **quality** and **maintainability**. That's why GWT can be a good choice.